# Sorting CouchDB Views By Value

Tags: sorting, couchdb

I'm testing out CouchDB to see how it could handle logging some search results.  What I'd like to do is produce a view where I can produce the top queries from the results.  At the moment I have something like this:

**Example document portion**

```
{
  "query": "+dangerous +dogs",
  "hits": "123"
}
```

**Map function**
(Not exactly what I need/want but it's good enough for testing)

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.query) {
    var split = doc.query.split(" ");
    for (var i in split) {
      emit(split[i], 1);
    }
  }
}
```

**Reduce Function**

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
  return sum(values);
}
```

Now this will get me results in a format where a query term is the key and the count for that term on the right, which is great.  But I'd like it ordered by the value, not the key.  From the sounds of it, this is not yet possible with CouchDB.

So does anyone have any ideas of how I can get a view where I have an ordered version of the query terms & their related counts?  I'm very new to CouchDB and I just can't think of how I'd write the functions needed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is true that there is no dead-simple answer. There are several patterns however.

1. http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_Snippets#Retrieve_the_top_N_tags. I do not personally like this because they acknowledge that it is a brittle solution, and the code is not relaxing-looking.
2. Avi's answer, which is to sort in-memory in your application.
3. [couchdb-lucene](http://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene/) which it seems everybody finds themselves needing eventually!
4. What I like is what Chris said in Avi's quote. Relax. In CouchDB, databases are lightweight and excel at giving you a unique perspective of your data. These days, the buzz is all about filtered replication which is all about slicing out subsets of your data to put in a separate DB.

   Anyway, the basics are simple. You take your `.rows` from the view output and you insert it into a separate DB which simply emits keyed on the count. An additional trick is to write a very simple `_list` function. Lists "render" the raw couch output into different formats. Your `_list` function should output

   ```
   { "docs":
       [ {..view row1...},
         {..view row2...},
         {..etc...}
       ]
   }
   ```

   What that will do is format the view output exactly the way the `_bulk_docs` API requires it. Now you can pipe curl directly into another curl:

   ```
   curl host:5984/db/_design/myapp/_list/bulkdocs_formatter/query_popularity \
    | curl -X POST host:5984/popularity_sorter/_design/myapp/_view/by_count
   ```
5. In fact, if your list function can handle all the docs, you may just have it sort them itself and return them to the client sorted.

Comment: Great answer so thanks JHS. Plenty of options for me to look into.

Comment: You're welcome. If it wasn't clear I would say first choice = sort in the client; second choice = use an alternative view (both of which AVI identified more succinctly!)

Comment: I admire the effort but this is pretty much a turn off. What do I get in return ?

Comment: could you expand on the third option: `couchdb-lucene`.  It's not clear to me how to use a full text index to quickly rank tags (or any other similar reduced view results).

Comment: Link Retrieve_the_top_N_tags seems to be broken. Can you describe this approach, please?

Comment: The suggested solutions are , in my opinion all indirect or incomplete...
Further - the recommended approach above does not solve a condition where you want to set a limit on a large result set and want it sorted before fetching... My pick goes out to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687297/couchdb-search-or-filtering-on-key-array) answering which suggests adding the desired sorted value into the key and performing a range query (start, end keys). See details in the link. For reverse sorting try [this post](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html#reversed)

Comment: The text from the link Retrieve_the_top_N_tags is still available in their wiki history: https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_Snippets?action=recall&rev=42#Retrieve_the_top_N_tags.

Answer (score 13):

This [came up](http://markmail.org/thread/ygiz7wbmrel7q6mw) on the CouchDB-user mailing list, and Chris Anderson, one of the primary developers, wrote:

> This is a common request, but not supported directly by CouchDB's
>   views -- to do this you'll need to copy the group-reduce query to
>   another database, and build a view to sort by value.
>
> This is a tradeoff we make in favor of dynamic range queries and
>   incremental indexes.

I needed to do this recently as well, and I ended up doing it in my app tier. This is easy to do in JavaScript:

```
db.view('mydesigndoc', 'myview', {'group':true}, function(err, data) {

    if (err) throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));

    data.rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.value - b.value;
    });

    data.rows.reverse(); // optional, depending on your needs

    // do something with the data…
});
```

This example runs in [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and uses [node-couchdb](http://github.com/felixge/node-couchdb), but it could easily be adapted to run in a browser or another JavaScript environment. And of course the concept is portable to any programming language/environment.

HTH!

Comment: I expanded on the dedicated DB to sort however sorting in the application is likely to work in most situations. For the OP maybe not if these are search terms but still.. :)

Comment: you can avoid the `data.rows.reverse()` simply by changing your sort function to `return b.value - a.value`

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question but I feel it still deserves a decent answer (I spent at least 20 minutes on searching for the correct answer...)

I disapprove of the other suggestions in the answers here and feel that they are unsatisfactory. Especially I don't like the suggestion to sort the rows in the applicative layer, as it doesn't scale well and doesn't deal with a case where you need to limit the result set in the DB.

The better approach that I came across is suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687297/couchdb-search-or-filtering-on-key-array) and it posits that if you need to sort the values in the query you should add them into the key set and then query the key using a range - specifying a desired key and loosening the value range. For example if your key is composed of country, state and city:

```
emit([doc.address.country,doc.address.state, doc.address.city], doc);
```

Then you query just the country and get free sorting on the rest of the key components:

```
startkey=["US"]&endkey=["US",{}]
```

In case you also need to reverse the order - note that simple defining `descending: true` will not suffice. You actually need to reverse the start and end key order, i.e.:

```
startkey=["US",{}]&endkey=["US"]
```

See more reference at this great [source](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html#reversed).

Comment: Great idea. Got me moving quickly. It feels like this is the only real answer on how to sort in the view.

Comment: This is a great answer and worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure about the 1 you have as your returned result, but I'm positive this should do the trick:

`emit([doc.hits, split[i]], 1);`

The [rules of sorting](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation#Collation_Specification) are defined in the docs.

Comment: I shouldn't have thrown the hits parameter in there.  That's a bit of a red herring.  What I've got at the moment is something that creates something like this: Key: +dangerous  Value: 25 .  Where 25 means that 25 people entered a query containing the text "+dangerous".

The code came from the CouchDB wiki here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_Snippets#Retrieve_the_top_N_tags.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Avi's answer, I came up with this Couchdb list function that worked for my needs, which is simply a report of most-popular events (key=event name, value=attendees).

```
ddoc.lists.eventPopularity = function(req, res) {
  start({ headers : { "Content-type" : "text/plain" } });
  var data = []
  while(row = getRow()) {
    data.push(row);
  }
  data.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.value - b.value;
  }).reverse();
  for(i in data) {
    send(data[i].value + ': ' + data[i].key + "\n");
  }
}
```

For reference, here's the corresponding view function:

```
ddoc.views.eventPopularity = {
  map : function(doc) {
    if(doc.type == 'user') {
      for(i in doc.events) {
        emit(doc.events[i].event_name, 1);
      }
    }
  },
  reduce : '_count'
}
```

And the output of the list function (snipped):

```
165: Design-Driven Innovation: How Designers Facilitate the Dialog
165: Are Your Customers a Crowd or a Community?
164: Social Media Mythbusters
163: Don't Be Afraid Of Creativity! Anything Can Happen
159: Do Agencies Need to Think Like Software Companies?
158: Customer Experience: Future Trends & Insights
156: The Accidental Writer: Great Web Copy for Everyone
155: Why Everything is Amazing But Nobody is Happy
```

Answer (score 0):

Every solution above will break couchdb performance I think. I am very new to this database. As I know couchdb views prepare results before it's being queried. It seems we need to prepare results manually. For example each search term will reside in database with hit counts. And when somebody searches, its search terms will be looked up and increments hit count. When we want to see search term popularity, it will emit (hitcount, searchterm) pair.

Answer (score 0):

The Link Retrieve_the_top_N_tags seems to be broken, but I found another solution [here](http://tobyho.com/2009/10/07/retrieve-the-top-n-tags-in/).

Quoting the dev who wrote that solution:

> rather than returning the results keyed by the tag in the map step, I would emit every occurrence of every tag instead. Then in the reduce step, I would calculate the aggregation values grouped by tag using a hash, transform it into an array, sort it, and choose the top 3.

As stated in the comments, the only problem would be in case of a long tail:

> Problem is that you have to be careful with the number of tags you obtain; if the result is bigger than 500 bytes, you'll have couchdb complaining about it, since "reduce has to effectively reduce". 3 or 6 or even 20 tags shouldn't be a problem, though.

It worked perfectly for me, check the link to see the code !

Comment: The text from the link Retrieve_the_top_N_tags is still available from their wiki history: https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_Snippets?action=recall&rev=42#Retrieve_the_top_N_tags.