# how to query with uncertainty a design view with complex nested keys

Tags: couchdb

I'm having access on a CouchDB view which emits documents having keys of two arrays of four integers like `[[int, int, int, int], [int, int, int, int]]`. In a concrete example those correspond to start-date and end-date of the document:

```
[[2017, 5, 5, 10], [2017, 7, 2, 11]]
 Y      m  d  H     Y     m  d  H
```

#### I'm able to get documents matching a period

```
request="localhorst/dbname/_design/a/_view/period"
request+="?key=\[\[2017,5,5,10\],\[2017,7,2,11\]\]"
curl -sX GET $request
```

#### Question: How to ignore the "hour" field H?

What if the boundaries are partially unknown? How to get all documents within a given period, like `2017-05-05` until `2017-07-02`? In other words, how can I ignore the last columns of each boundary?

I tried to use `startKey` and `endKey`

```
request="localhorst/dbname/_design/a/_view/period"
request+="?startKey=\[\[2017,5,5\],\[2017,7,2\]\]"
request+="&endKey=\[\[2017,5,5,\{\}\],\[2017,7,2,\{\}\]\]"
curl -sX GET $request
```

This does not work since it gets documents with the correct lower bound but the upper bound is wrong, e.g.:

```
[[2017,4,5,10],[2017,7,2,12]] <- excluded,  OK
[[2017,5,5,10],[2017,7,2,12]] <- contained, OK
[[2017,5,5,11],[2017,7,2,12]] <- contained, OK
[[2017,5,5,10],[2017,8,2,12]] <- contained, ERROR
```

Comment: My first suggestion would be to try Mango.

Comment: Just a tip: Why not use RFC3339 dates instead of a custom format? It's sortable, and many programs/libraries understand it natively.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting suggestions I will keep them im mind for future development. In the current case I cannot decide about the format oder data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. If you use complex keys, you can perform partial matches with `startkey` and `endkey` by dropping items to the right of the key array only, not by dropping items internally in the key array.

Without knowing how your documents are structured, it's difficult to offer more than generic advice. I'd look to emit a single time stamp vector and use startkey and endkey to find the range, rather than trying to use the range as the key. However, this approach might not fit your model.

Otherwise, as suggested above, using Mango may be your best bet.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I guessed something like that but was hoping there is some secret magic I have not discovered yet :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use empty for the start keys and empty object {} as the last.

So 2017-05-05 until 2017-07-02 would be

`[2017,05,05]` to `[2017,07,02,{},{},{}]`

You can refer to this answer: [couchdb search or filtering on key array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687297/couchdb-search-or-filtering-on-key-array)