# Sorting CouchDB data using couch-lucene

Tags: lucene, couchdb

I have some summation data that was very easy to generate using some relatively simple map/reduce views.  But we want to sort the data based on the group-reduced view *values* (not the keys).  It was suggested that we could use [couchdb-lucene](http://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene/) to do this.  But how?  It's not clear to me how to use a full text index to quickly rank this sort of data.

**What we already have**

An oversimplified example view looks something like the following:

```
by_sender: {
  map: "function(doc) { emit(doc.sender, 1); }",
  reduce: "function(keys, values, rereduce) { return sum(values); }"
}
```

Which returns results somewhat like the following (when run with `group=true`):

```
 {"rows":[
 {"key":"a@example.com","value":2},
 {"key":"aaa@example.com","value":1},
 {"key":"aaap@example.com","value":34},
 {"key":"aabb@example.com","value":1},
 ... thousands or tens of thousands of rows ...
 ]}
```

**What we want**

Those are sorted by the key, but I need to sort it data according the values, like so:

```
 {"rows":[
 {"key":"xyzzy@example.com","value":847},
 {"key":"adam@example.com","value":345},
 {"key":"karl@example.com","value":99},
 {"key":"aaap@example.com","value":34},
 ... thousands or tens of thousands of rows ...
 ]}
```

And I need it sorted as quickly as is reasonably possible (e.g. if it only takes <100ms to update the indexes, it shouldn't take 1 minute before the new data is reflected in queries).

**More context: what we already tried**

The best answer on [Sorting CouchDB Views By Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817703/sorting-couchdb-views-by-value) gives four viable options, which we've tried in increasing order of difficulty:

1. First we sorted the results client side, but that was *way* too slow.
2. Next we created a list function which sorts the data.  A little faster, but still too slow.
3. Chained Map-Reduce Views should handle this problem easily.

   - Someone pointed out Cloudant's [Chained Map-Reduce Views](http://support.cloudant.com/customer/portal/articles/359310-chained-mapreduce-views).  They are not in  [BigCouch](http://bigcouch.cloudant.com/) but are part of Cloudant's services, which are unfortunately not in our budget at this time.
   - I started an application layer implementation using the _bulk_docs API.  It is tricky if you want to keep updates as snappy as possible while avoiding race conditions, etc.  I can continue with this approach, but it is *not* relaxing.  :(
4. The answer suggested using [couchdb-lucene](http://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene/).  But I'm not nearly familiar enough with full-text search to understand how to get it to do anything more sophisticated than index the document and return a search result.  I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Hi, I not sure what do you mean by the list view? You can try to insert the group results into a separate database, and you can easily do a sort. I guess you can use make use of a cronjob to update it regularly.

Comment: Sorry, I meant list *function* not list *view*.  I've updated the question.

Comment: I *also* forgot to mention that we need this data to be as close to real-time as is reasonably possible.  If it only takes <100ms to absorb the new documents into the various view indexes, we don't want to wait 1 minute for a cronjob to get around to it.  I'm also open to the possibility that couchdb is just wrong for this particular task.  Another option is to have a daemon monitoring the changes feed and issue a redis `zincrby messages:by_sender 1 $sender` for each new document.

Comment: Are you doing some logging? I'm thinking you can use separate document to track the count. When inserting a new document, lookup the document corresponding to the email address, if not exist, create a new document, if exist, just plus +1.

Comment: Yes, we could absolutely go with the dual entry approach.  But if I'm going that way, I'll probably store the counts in a redis zset instead of a couchdb document.  :)

Comment: oh, great. I not too sure is redis support ordering?

Comment: @nicholasa.evans Did you find a proper solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Needed to count the votes per article and sort the articles by their number of votes. I have solved using a separate document to track each vote, and another document that stores the votes count per article. Let's call them: article, vote, score.
I wrote a cron script that update the score for each article, counting the "not registered" votes. The script calls a view using the `_count` reduce function, where only the "not registered" votes are emitted (registered == FALSE). I use the option group_results to have the number of not registered votes per article, then I update the score for each article, marking "registered" the votes. At this point I have a view that emit as key the score of each article and as value the article id. So the articles can be ordered by score. Conflicts are avoided using this tecnique.