# Use a view to get the same suffix like maindomain name

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I have some documents, how can use a view to get the document which have the same domain name for their email address. like all the document with @gmail.com or @yahoo.com, if endkey can get that results?

Here is what I wrote a view on map, But I do not think this is good idea

```
  function(doc) {
    for (var i in doc.emails) {
     if (doc.emails[i].emailAddress.toLowerCase().indexOf("@yahoo.ibm.com")!=-1) {
                    emit(doc.emails[i].emailAddress.toLowerCase(), doc);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To make things clear, the endkey parameter is not looking for a suffix. Startkey and endkey are like the limits of keys to get. For example, you could get the document with the id 1 to the id 10  `startkey="1"&endkey="10"` .

In your case, you want to make a view that will group your documents by their domain name. I created a design document with a `byDomain` view. The mapping function looks like this :

```
    function(doc){
        if(doc.email){ //I used the document's property email for my view.
            //Now, we will emit an array key. The first value will be the domain.
            //To get the domain, we split the string with the character '@' and we take what comes after.
            //Feel free to add more validations
            //The second key will be the document id. We don't emit any values. It's faster to simply add
            //the includes_docs query parameter.
            emit([doc.email.split('@')[1],doc._id]); 
        }
    }
```

1. Let's query all my documents to show you what I have

Request : `http://localhost:5984/test/_all_docs?include_docs=true`
Response:

```
    {"total_rows":4,"offset":0,"rows":[
    {"id":"7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202000e5f","key":"7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202000e5f","value":{"rev":"1-c84cf3bf33e1d853f99a4a5cb0a4af74"},"doc":{"_id":"7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202000e5f","_rev":"1-c84cf3bf33e1d853f99a4a5cb0a4af74","email":"steve@gmail.com"}},
    {"id":"7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202001101","key":"7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202001101","value":{"rev":"1-53a8a9f2a24d812fe3c98ad0fe020197"},"doc":{"_id":"7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202001101","_rev":"1-53a8a9f2a24d812fe3c98ad0fe020197","email":"foo@example.com"}},
    {"id":"7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202001b02","key":"7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202001b02","value":{"rev":"1-cccec02fe7172fb637ac430f0dd25fa2"},"doc":{"_id":"7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202001b02","_rev":"1-cccec02fe7172fb637ac430f0dd25fa2","email":"bar@gmail.com"}},
    {"id":"_design/emails","key":"_design/emails","value":{"rev":"4-76785063c7dbeec96c495db76a8faded"},"doc":{"_id":"_design/emails","_rev":"4-76785063c7dbeec96c495db76a8faded","views":{"byDomain":{"map":"\t\tfunction(doc){\n\t\t\tif(doc.email){ //I used the document's property email for my view.\n\t\t\t\t//Now, we will emit an array key. The first value will be the domain.\n\t\t\t\t//To get the domain, we split the string with the character '@' and we take what comes after.\n\t\t\t\t//Feel free to add more validations\n\t\t\t\t//The second key will be the document id. We don't emit any values. It's faster to simply add\n\t\t\t\t//the includes_docs query parameter.\n\t\t\t\temit([doc.email.split('@')[1],doc._id]); \n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}"}},"language":"javascript"}}
    ]}
```

As you can see, I got few minimalist documents with the property "email" set.

2. Let's query my view without any parameters

Request :  `http://localhost:5984/test/_design/emails/_view/byDomain`

Response :

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
    {"id":"7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202001101","key":["example.com","7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202001101"],"value":null},
    {"id":"7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202000e5f","key":["gmail.com","7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202000e5f"],"value":null},
    {"id":"7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202001b02","key":["gmail.com","7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202001b02"],"value":null}
    ]}
```

3. Let's query only documents with that have the gmail.com domain.

Request : `http://localhost:5984/test/_design/emails/_view/byDomain?startkey=["gmail.com"]&endkey=["gmail.com","\ufff0"]`

Result :

```
    {"total_rows":3,"offset":1,"rows":[
        {"id":"7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202000e5f","key":["gmail.com","7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202000e5f"],"value":null},
        {"id":"7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202001b02","key":["gmail.com","7f34ec3b9332ab4e555bfca202001b02"],"value":null}
        ]}
```

Comment: Hi Alexis, yes, I tried and I believe this is very good and reasonable solution, Thank you for your help

Comment: @Jamesjin Feel free to accept this answer if it helped you!

Comment: Hi Alexis, one question hope you can help me out, how can I get a result which is sorted within descending order of the “value” value? here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800308/how-can-i-get-a-map-reduce-result-which-is-sorted-within-descending-order-of-the/38800358#38800358    thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple map function for this:

```
function (doc) {
  var domain = doc.email.split('@').pop();
  // this logic is fairly hack-ish, you may want to be more sophisticated
  emit(domain);
}
```

Then you can simply pass `key=gmail.com` to get the results you want from the view. I would also add `include_docs=true` instead of emitting the entire document as your value.

You can read more about views in [the official CouchDB docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/views/intro.html).

Comment: Thank you, do you know how can I get a result which is sorted within descending order of the “value” value? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800308/how-can-i-get-a-map-reduce-result-which-is-sorted-within-descending-order-of-the

Comment: @Jamesjin There is not simple way. Also, the answer I would provide would be very similar to [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817703/sorting-couchdb-views-by-value).